# ruby on rails implement generic search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I have 2 tables in my DB - an "illness" table and a "symptoms" table.
I've implemented a generic search for searching both tables.
My goal is to display the results in the result page, each result should be a hyperlink that leads to the result "show" page (illness/id/show or symptom/id/show).

As i'm passing generic results to the result page, I don't really know whether the current result is an illness or a symptom. I wonder what is the best way to get this information (Should I try to collect this informaiton in the controller and somehow pass it to the html? should I somehow run another query from the html?)

I'm using rails 3.x, and my controller code looks like this:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @results = Illness.search(params[:search]) + Symptom.search(params[:search])

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @results }
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to be worried about it. Let the Rails to serve it:

```
   - @results.each do |result|
     = link_to 'Show', result
```

And you'll get the proper link based on the result's type.

And one more. What the `show` in URL has to do with the `show` **action** in your examples like: `symptom/id/show`? The `show` action is mapped by default to `GET /model/id` path.

Comment: wow. thanks. There's so much to learn in this language. and thanks for the comment regarding the links.